# Thunderbird cannot be re-opened from Dash

Tags: thunderbird

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 (on Wayland) if I open thunderbird from the Dash and then close it it cannot be reopened from the Dash. If I click on the Thunderbird icon nothing happens. If I open a teminal and type in "thunderbird" then it opens normally.

Comment: You may want to check the behaviour on Xorg: on the log in screen, click the cog icon to log in to an Xorg session. That would allow to confirm that the issue is related to running Wayland.